# .run application won't run even after I became a root user

Tags: permissions, root

I downloaded a .run setup file for a program. But when I try to run it, it says:

There has been an error. This installer requires root privileges. Please become superuser before executing the installer.

I ran commands like `sudo -i`, `sudo -s` and `sudo su` in the terminal. And when I run any of these commands, the `$` sign turns into a `#` sign, and based on what I found on the internet, this means that I am a root user, but when I try running the installer again, it still gives me that error.

Am I missing something here ?
(I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: Please add output of `file *.run` (or `file filename.run` if you know exact *filename* in the needed directory).

Comment: Run it with `sudo bash -x setup.run`  and see the last several lines. Find the failed "am I `root`" check.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I made a foolish mistake. I was trying to run the file by clicking on it but what I should've done was to use the terminal instead.
Don't make the same mistake as I did.

1- Go to the directory where your *.run file is located.

2- Right click and choose "Open in terminal"(Or open the terminal first and navigate to the directory. For example cd /home/[username]/Downloads).

3- Run the following command to make your file executable :
sudo chmod 755 file_name.run

4- Run this command to execute the installer :
sudo ./file_name.run

Hope this helped. Sorry if I wasn't clear when I asked the question.